# Draw arc within polyline THREE.JS

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have points like this:

```
    "POLYLINE":[[
        {"x":"-6094.1665707632401","y":"3074.764386330728","r":""},
        {"x":"-699.22595358468595","y":"1099.941236568309","r":""},                
        {"x":"-4940.397089330264","y":"576.87996358328382","r":""},
        {"x":"-1329.5259580814709","y":"3149.4874087018579","r":"0.5163456475719181"},
        {"x":"-6094.1665707632401","y":"3074.764386330728","r":""}
    ]]
```

where x y are vertices of a polyline and r is the radius if it is an arc.
i can manage drawing the are if this isnt possible but i would need to jump past the arc in the script

```
function DRAWpline(vert){
            vert = JSON.parse(vert);
            var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
                color: 0x0000ff
            });
            var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();

            for (var i = 0; i < vert.length; i++) {     
                if(vert[i]['r'] != ""){
                    geometry.vertices.push(new THREE.Vector3(vert[i]['x'], vert[i]['y'], 0));
                } else {

                }
            }

            var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);



            scene.add(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, could do the job:

```
var p0 = new THREE.Vector3(vert[i]['x'], 0, 0);
var p1 = new THREE.Vector3(vert[i]['x'], vert[i]['y'], 0);
var p2 = new THREE.Vector3(vert[i+1]['x'], vert[i+1]['y'], 0);
var startAngle = Math.acos(p0.dot(p1)/(p0.length()*p1.length()));
var angle = Math.acos(p1.dot(p2)/(p1.length()*p2.length()));
geometry = new THREE.CircleGeometry(radius, nbSegments, startAngle, angle);
// remove center vertex
geometry.vertices.splice(0,1);
```

Add a check on vert[i+1] is exiting before compute p2

Comment: Oups, after re-reading your post. I think i missunderstand you. when r  is defined X,Y is the start point of the arc or the center of the arc? If it's the center, my code is uncorrect

Comment: Thanks again bud! I never took any math classes and i dropped out so i am having a really hard time with this trig and what not. I ended up using a function to merge geometry ill post the code when its finished.

Comment: Hey man could you double check this code? i implemented it and it places the arcs way off target

Comment: Could you explain what is X,Y when r is setted? It's the arc center or the first vertex of the arc? And Is the previous vertex is the first vertex of the arc? Is the next vertex is the last vertex of the arc?

Comment: sorry actually the code is perfect. what i thought was the radius is actually the tangent of the arc with 0 being a straight line and 2 being a circle

Comment: if you want to help me out you can read the "bulge to arc" here http://www.lee-mac.com/bulgeconversion.html

Comment: Am I crazy or does this not totally answer the question? Wouldn't this assume the arc is centered around 0,0?